# Why does changing my render request in views.py break my ability to import images in my base.html?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, django-settings

In my views.py, I have a function for my homepage;

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def home(request): 
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_object)

    posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request, "main/home.html", {'user_profile': user_profile}) #This is the problem line
```

and my HTML runs perfectly;

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="{% static 'css/images/uReflect.png' %}" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <nav>
```

[image: Page working]

But when I change my home function in views.py to the code below, my page stops working. I have no idea how an error with 'post.image' would correlate to me accessing my images that are independent of posts, and exist in a separate folder. The weirdest part to me is how the error says "NoReverseMatch at /home" but the error doesn't even occur in home.html, it occurs in base.html. Although, home.html does extend base.html;

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def home(request): 
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_object)

    posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request, "main/home.html", {'user_profile': user_profile, 'posts': posts}) # Change made here with posts
```

[image: Page not working]

Comment: Perhaps your base.html is doing something with a context variable named "post". Check that

Comment: I don't believe that's the case, "post" doesn't appear in base.html

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of `posts`? maybe try this `postObjs = Post.objects.all()`. `return render(request, "main/home.html", {'user_profile': user_profile, 'postObjs': postObjs})`

Comment: add `posts` to render return `render(request, "main/home.html", {'user_profile': user_profile, `posts`:posts})` problem is on your `home.html` when you are rendering posts

Comment: [@AnonymousUser](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15188026/anonymoususer)  this worked for me! How did you know that this would work? I'm still new to Django and didn't even think of this solution.